# terminal commands "command not found"

Tags: touchpad, hp

I'm very new to Ubuntu and having a few problems. I'm trying to debrick my HP  Touchpad via the jc scullin wiki method, but when I'm inputting a command in the terminal such as `Run" cd Downloads"` I just keep getting back `! command not found`. Is there something I'm missing? An install or different command? Just following the instructions provided for the process and starting to lose the plot.

Comment: Could you tell what is jc scullin wiki method? Or maybe provide a link to it?

Comment: post the full error report.

Comment: if you're typing `Run "cd Downloads"`, then you're being too literal in your reading of the instructions. He's telling you to run the command `cd Downloads`, that's what you'd have to type. If you're confused about this I suggest an entry-level command-line tutorial such as http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php.

Answer (score 1):

The message, "command not found" means that you are entering something that the terminal doesn't know what to do with.  More simply, you are entering the command incorrectly or it is not a command at all.

The [manual pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/) can help find the command you want, plus show you how to use it.  From the terminal, try:

```
man man
man apt-get
man -k cd
man -k cd downloads
```

The first command is to show the manual page for the manual pager.  The second is for an important command used to install new programs (installed from [packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware) in Ubuntu), remove them, or update your system.  The third command above uses the -k option, which means to search for commands, packages, and (more importantly) the descriptions for them.  You'll get a list of commands with that string.  If you spot one that looks right, use the man command to see what it does.

This will help you figure out what to do.  If you need help with a specific problem, you need to describe it, give [links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to wiki page(s) you are referencing, copy/paste the commands or pictures of what you are trying with the output.